# Does 2 different eclipse installations use different JVM?

Tags: java, eclipse, jvm

By Simply Running same code in two Different eclipse can we say that code is running in two different jvm on same system.

Comment: what is this supposed to tell us? where is the question?

Answer (score 1):

No. The JVM is a virtual machine the **Java** uses. Eclipse just runs programs on that virtual machine. It doesn't create it.

If you install two different eclipse versions and set one eclipse to run on some specific JVM as explained [here](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini)
and the other to run on another JVM, then you can have them running on different JVMs on one machine. But there's no point in doing that

Comment: Means I have  two Client.java  running  different eclipse but the single JVM is Used by both Eclipse is it like that

Comment: @Ashu yes. That's what it means

Comment: @Ashu did you understand the answer?

Comment: 1Ecclipse -> 1JVm

Comment: @Ashu not exactly. One eclipse **version** configured to 1 jvm. If you have 2 versions of eclipse, then you can run on two JVMs. But you don't need two JVMs

Comment: 2Eclipse ->2JVM ,2Eclipse ->3JVM ,I am i correct, OR  1Eclipse,2Eclipse 3Eclipse ---> (All Share same JVM)

Comment: @Ashu you don't need more than one JVM. So you don't need to bother with all of this

Comment: i have only Eclipse Mars

Comment: @Ashu again, my answer stays the same. You don't need more than one JVM

Comment: @Ashu did you understand it?

Answer (score 1):

If you're wondering whether you can use two different JVM versions by launching them different eclipse setups, that could be possible.

If you're wondering whether they'll run in the same JVM instance, the answer is no. For example, if you intend to use a *synchronized* function to limit access to a shared resource like a file, it's not going to work because that will only work within the same JVM instance. If you want to isolate your applications so that one can use all available memory without impacting the other, yes, they'll be isolated by running them from different eclipse instances.
You actually don't even need to start Eclipse twice. You can run your app twice from the same Eclipse.